# GradientBoostingClassifier analog in R

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Is there an analog for Python [sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html) in R language?

I know there are R packages for gradient boosting: [gbm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/index.html), [mboost](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mboost/index.html), [TDboost](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TDboost/index.html), [gbev](http://ftp.auckland.ac.nz/software/CRAN/src/contrib/Descriptions/gbev.html), [bst](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bst/index.html), etc.

But which one package, which function and with what parameters I should use to get same results, as with GradientBoostingClassifier in Python using default parameters?

Comment: if you want consistency between R and Python, your best bet is to use XGBoost.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut thanks, but actually I need it for educational reasons. You see there is a tutorial written in Python using GradientBoostingClassifier, and my aim is to translate it in R. So I actually need an equivalent which will give same results in output.

Comment: Late comment, but don't you need the gbm package? Otherwise nowadays you can use h2o in both R and python.